# Fiber Speed Drop RV320

Tags: router, fiber, cisco-router

Not sure if this is the right site to ask this, but I noticed there are a number of RV320-related questions, so here goes.

I have an AT&T fiber connection to my home that connects to my LAN through a Cisco RV320 firewall/router. The modem is an Arris 5268ac supplied by AT&T.

At least once a day I have to reboot the 5268ac in order to restore the gigabit connection speed the fiber offers (something causes it to drop to around 45 megabit after some period of time). Sometimes I have to reboot it twice in order to restore the higher speed.

The problem seems to involve the connection, or interaction, between the 5268ac and the RV320. I say this because if I connect directly into the 5268ac (it's a 4 port router in addition to being a modem) I'll get the full gigabit speed, even while the connection over my LAN, through the RV320, shows only 45 megabit.

Yet rebooting the RV320 doesn't solve the problem. Only rebooting the 5268ac once or twice fixes things.

This is more than a little bit of a headscratcher for me. I'm used to connections dying completely as a result of configuration problems. But losing 95% of the speed while maintaining the connection is a new one on me.

**Additional Info**

The RV320 has been updated to the latest firmware. The 5268ac updates are controlled/pushed by AT&T, so I can only presume it's up to date, too.

I have contacted AT&T and they tested the line from their end and found no evidence of problems. That's consistent with my observations that a direct connection to the 5268ac, rather than going through my LAN (which goes through the RV320), always gets me the gigabit speed I'm expecting.

This behavior has been in evidence for a bit over 6 months, but the frequency of needing to reboot the 5268ac to recover gigabit speeds has been increasing over time, to the point where the higher speed now only "holds" for less than a day.

Comment: Any applicable firmware updates available?

Comment: I updated the RV320, but that didn't solve the problem. AT&T controls the 5268ac updates, so I presume it's up to date.

Comment: When I had this problem with a similar Arris product, although in that case I would actually be disconnected from the service, it was caused by ingress noise.  Have you contacted AT&T for perhaps a replacement modem?  Have you tried to replace all network cables?  While the speed is slower, have you contacted AT&T, in order for them to test the line?  Has this always happen or this new behavior?  Please edit your question instead of submitting a comment

Answer (score 0):

Fiber doesn't need a modem. It needs an ONT (Optical Network Terminal), which is usually installed outside at the demarc (the demarcation point where the telco's wiring connects to your house wiring). Ethernet is usually run through the wall to an indoor router.

Your 5268ac is a DSL (not fiber) modem and router, and it also has a Ethernet WAN port so it can be used as just a router. I'm 99% certain you have an Ethernet cable from the ONT in your Ethernet WAN port, not a telephone line in your DSL modem WAN port.

So you're running two routers back-to-back with potentially no benefit. Ditch the 5268ac if it serves no purpose and just causes flakiness. Just plug the Ethernet cable from your ONT into the Ethernet WAN port of your RV320. You may need to copy the WAN port settings from your 5268ac onto your RV320.

Comment: Thanx, @Spiff; very helpful explanation (I'd wondered about that, too, since the ONT connection looks like an RJ-45...but I wasn't sure).

However, the 5268ac provides one other service that I'm unclear how to handle: VOIP. In other words, my phone line ties into an RJ-12 (?) jack on the 5268ac. The Cisco RV320 doesn't have a VOIP "outlet".

Do you know if I put the 5268ac downstream of the RV320 to preserve the VOIP connection? Or do you know of a router that has a VOIP outlet?